# Wildfly 10 / NetBeans 8.2: Issue creating Message-driven Bean

Tags: netbeans, jms, wildfly

I have a problem after adding a message queue to Wildfly 10.1 (I'm using NetBeans 8.2). The message queue appears under the Resources/JMS Resources/JMS Destinations node in Wildfly Application Server, but when I create a message-driven bean using the NetBeans wizard, the Server Destinations drop-down is blank. (see screenshot).

[image: NetBeans Dialog]

It should show the jms queue I created. I've tried restarting Wildfly and NetBeans, but to no avail. Can anyone advise a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That certainly looks like a bug (or at least a relic from the Glassfish support code), you may want to file a bug report for that. But in the mean time, it's not hard to work around. Assuming you created (via the Wildfly console) a queue named `testq` with jndi name `java:/jms/testq` you can just enter `jms/testq` as a "Project Destination" in the wizard and it will work. This will lead to the following (minimal) code

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "jms/testq")
    ,@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class SomeMessageBean implements MessageListener {
```

and the onMessage handler:

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
}
```

You could as well create a regular class and add the @MessageDriven annotation, there's really nothing magical about mdb's

Comment: I'm completely new to Wildfly and MDBs but my code is very similar to yours above.. Your workaround seems to have done the trick though. My  My trial web application now works, thanks.